# How to compare string command line arguments in C?

Tags: c, pointers, command-line-arguments, string-comparison

Sorry, I'm a rookie in C. What I am trying to do is just to print something if *--help* parameter is entered to the terminal like `./program --help`. So the code is this:

```
char *HELP = "--help";
char *argv1 = argv[1];

if (argv1 == HELP) {
    printf("argv[1] result isaa %s\n", argv[1]);
}
```

So even if I use --help parameter it does not pass through the if condition. So what could be the reason behind that?

Comment: Note that you will have to include different .h files anytime you call functions.  So, your question below about `warning: implicit declaration of function ‘strcmp’` can be answered by entering the command `man strcmp` which will tell you which file your function is defined in and therefore needs to be included.  (If your OS is not *nix based, just google 'man strcmp' to get the same information)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That's not how you compare strings in C. Use `strcmp` or `strncmp`:

```
if (strcmp(argv1, HELP) == 0)
```

Include `string.h` to get access to those.

Comment: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘strcmp’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]

Comment: @SarpKaya `#include <string.h>`

Comment: For a beginner, it's (in my opinion) much clearer to compare against 0, instead of using the `!` operator.

Answer (score 4):

That is comparing the addresses, not the content. Use [`strcmp()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp):

```
if (0 == strcmp(HELP, argv1))
{
    printf("argv[1] result isaa %s\n", argv[1]);
}
```

Be sure and check that `argc > 1` before accessing `argv[1]`.

Answer (score 3):

In C, there is no string type. You've declared `char *HELP`, so HELP is a `char *`, not a string. In the if, you are comparing two pointers, instead of the string they point to.
You will want to call `strcmp` (string compare), a function that receives two `char *`, and compares the strings pointed by them.

Answer (score 0):

You shoul use strcmp.

```
result=strcmp(argv1,HELP);
if(result==0)
{
    --what you want
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`char *HELP = "--help";` - Here `--help` is a string literal which is a read only data in text segment. You are just assining the address to the pointer variable `HELP`.

`argv[1] will given you the address where the first commandline arguemet is stored.

So `argv[1]` and `HELP` are having different address. So the condition `(argv[1] == HELP)` is just checking the address stored in these two pointer variables. Always this will fail.

Actually you have to compare the content of these two pionters. For this you can impelement the string compare logic or use the `strcmp` function.

```
if (0 == strcmp(argv[1], HELP)
{
    //do your stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. my problem is solved by using `strncmp`.
`strcmp` doesnt work for my problem anyway

```
#include <string.h>


    if (strncmp(argv1, HELP,6) == 0) //6 is size of argument
    {
    //do smt
    }
```